# Uncaught ReferenceError: Keycloak is not defined

Tags: keycloak

[image: Issue details]

Unable to load admin console. I have setup Nginx confif

Comment: The reason is right there in your screenshot: You are trying to load an `http` resource from an `https` site. The browser does not permit that.

Comment: I know, But my issue is with keyckoak. I don't have any control over it.

Comment: The problem is not with keycloak. The problem is that the browser refuses to load the file that provides the keycloack code.

Answer (score 4):

As described in the documentation

nginx needs to provide `X-Fordward-For`  and `X-Forwarded-Proto` Header when acting as ssl proxy for keycloak

e.g like that

```
        location /
        {   
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
            proxy_pass http://keycloak;
        }
```

And you need to configure proxy adress forwarding in keycloak. Either by adding `proxy-address-forwarding="true"` to `http-listener` in the `standalone.xml` or by setting the environment variable `PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING: "true"` when using docker.

And finally, in case I'm allowed to give you an avdice: If you ask more specific/detailed questions you will get better answers. A screenshot with an error message and the info you "have a nginx" is normally not enough. Posting your full configuration is essential to provide you useful help.